# Is it impossible to have 2 blank lines between <p> tag? Markdown

Tags: html

HTML have bothered me since HTML1 emerged.

One thing is about line breaks.

http://jsfiddle.net/LhDFs/2/

```
<p>1</p>
<p>2</p>

<p>br1</p>
<br/>
<p>br2</p>

<p>p1</p>
foo
<p>p2</p>

<p>pp1</p>
    <p>foo</p>
<p>pp2</p>
```

p tag has 1 line between the element.

Is it impossible to have 2 blank lines between `<p>`? 
It appears `<br/>` or space symbol doesn't work for that.

Well, of course, it's possible to use `<br/>` instead of `<p>`, but now I tweak Markdown, especially gfm, so I need to preserve paragraph structure.

I short, it's way too strange that we never be able to have 2 blank lines as long as we stick on `<p>`.

What I consider is

```
foo


bar
```

2 blank lines:instead of

```
foo



bar
```

3 blank lines with p tag structure.

**EDIT:**

Well, what I intended is to have consistent structure of P tag, but thanks to everyone, I've got a hint that I can prepare multiple classed p tag with CSS hack.

This is truly hacky on first thought, but I think I can manage it. Appreciated to all comments.

**EDIT2:**

I thought we have solution for this, but it seems not;
I post another:

[It seems impossible to have 2 blank lines between p tags Without modification of the original elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18008474/it-seems-impossible-to-have-2-blank-lines-between-p-tags-without-modification-of)

Comment: Consider setting margins and/or padding between your paragraphs instead.  `p { margin: 3em 0; }`

Comment: Yea avoid `<br/>` at all costs these days.  CSS can do pretty much all of that a lot easier.

Comment: No, that can't be a solution. This is more fundamental issue of html tag.

Comment: @KenOKABE Are you saying that Brad is wrong?  He is right.  Use CSS styling to change the look and feel of your tags.

Comment: I think @KenOKABE is talking about white space in markup not showing up after being processed.

Comment: I did what Brad said. http://jsfiddle.net/LhDFs/4/ Just does not make sense...

Comment: What part of it does not make sense?  It's completely valid CSS.

Comment: I am not talking about CSS stuff. I know it applies Equally to the element. Why do you think line count changes by CSS equal application??

Comment: @KenOKABE I have no idea what you are trying to say in that last comment.  Could it be that you haven't realised you can use `2em` instead of `3em`?  Or any other value and unit of measurement, for that matter.

Comment: @KenOKABE you maintain consistant structure of your `<p>` via *CSS*

Comment: just for the record, using css to style your html is not even close to "hacky." this is standard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

White space in your mark up (new lines, spaces) will not show up on the front end of a website.

This:

```
<p>example</p>
<p>example</p>
```

Is the same as:

```
<p>
    example
</p>


<p>
    example
</p>
```

On a website, both those examples will appear exactly the same.

To control spacing, padding, margin and position on the front end of a website we use css:

**HTML**

```
<p>
    example
</p>
```

**CSS**

```css
p {
    padding-left: 20px;
}
```

Here is a demo showing different paragraph margins controlled by css:

**HTML**

```
<p class="noMargin">No margin</p>
<p class="noMargin">No margin</p>
<p class="noMargin">No margin</p>
<p>Default margin</p>
<p>Default margin</p>
<p>Default margin</p>
<p class="doubleMargin">Double margin</p>
<p class="doubleMargin">Double margin</p>
<p class="doubleMargin">Double margin</p>
```

**CSS**

```css
p.noMargin {
    margin: 0;
}
p.doubleMargin {
    margin: 2em 0;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LhDFs/7/)**

Comment: Thanks, but I know all of this stuff. Again, I'm 100% sure this is Not CSS issue. I am talking about line counts. Whatever magin/padding applied by CSS. IT's all applied to all lines or elements. This can't be a solution.

Comment: what part of this "can't be a solution"??? this is absolutely, 100% the solution.

Comment: @KenOKABE Nobody knows what you're talking about.

Comment: I'm sorry @KenOKABE, I don't understand what you mean by line counts.

Comment: Well, I misunderstood. I am sorry. You suggested the idea I can have multiple classed P tag. I understood now. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I thought we have solution for this, but it seems not; I post another:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18008474/it-seems-impossible-to-have-2-blank-lines-between-p-tags-without-modification-of

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly it seems to be working for me.
But one thing is the correct syntax for line break is:

```
<br>
<br />
```

Or style it like one of these

```
<p style="margin-bottom: 10px;">text</p>
<p style="line-height: 200%;">text</p>
```

A line height in percent of the current font size

Comment: Thanks. I've got an idea by 3dgoo pretty much well

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<br />
&nbsp;
<br />
```

**nbsp** means "non-breaking space".

Comment: Thanks, but it must be P tag to preserver the structure.

Comment: You can also use <p>&nbsp;</p>

Comment: Well, as long as we stick on a single p tag, it can't do. we must have p tag with multiple class for different margins.